# HTML attribute disabled="disabled" doesn't work with IE8

Tags: html, model-view-controller, input, internet-explorer-8

I have a ASP.NET MVC application. The code in the aspx is like that

```
<input '<%= ViewData["Disabled"] %>' class="Text1" type="text" name='test' value='0'/>
```

ViewData["Disabled"] contains at this state a string =

> 'disabled="disabled"'

the result in firefox:

```
<input class="Text1" type="text" value="0" name="test" disabled="disabled"/>
```

the result in IE8:

```
<input name="test" class="Text1" type="text" ?="" ?disabled="disabled" value="0"/>
```

Why is the output like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe try getting rid of the enclosing single-quotes:

```
<input <%= ViewData["Disabled"] %> class="Text1" type="text" name='test' value='0'/>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it might be the quotes

Try:

```
<input <%= ViewData["Disabled"] %> 
       class="Text1" 
       type="text" 
       name='test' 
       value='0'/>
```

Kindness,

Dan